# What is the advantage in OAuth2 of the implicit grant over Authorization Code grant

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

What is the advantage in OAuth2 of the implicit grant over authorization code grant?

Specifically I'm wondering why the implicit grant is recommended for public clients but the authorization code grant is not. They seem so similar that the difference is unimportant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare client action in both cases keeping in mind that client - is a piece of software you will have to write on your own.

In case of `Authorization code grant` client does those steps defined in spec:

> 1. The client requests an access token from the authorization server's token
>      endpoint by including the authorization code received in the previous step. When
>      making the request, the client authenticates with the authorization server. The
>      client includes the redirection URI used to obtain the authorization code for
>      verification.
> 2. The authorization server authenticates the client, validates the authorization code,
>      and ensures the redirection URI received matches the URI used to redirect the
>      client in step (C). If valid, the authorization server responds back with an access
>      token and optionally, a refresh token.

In case of `Implicit Grant` it has to do:

> 1. Receive an Access Token.

Now the answer is more or less trivial: the amount of code in first approach is unknown but could substantial against almost negligible for the second approach.

Answer (score 12):

The benefits of an authorization code step is as follows (from [OAuth 2.0 spec 1.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1)):

> The authorization code provides a few important security benefits such
> as the ability to authenticate the client, and the transmission of the
> access token directly to the client without passing it through the
> resource owner's user-agent, potentially exposing it to others,
> including the resource owner.

Generally if your client is server side (Web app) - you should use authorization code grant.  If it's a JavaScript based application (client side) - implicit is appropriate.  For mobile apps, authorization code grant type is preferred often if an external browser (not embedded) is used.

Client secrets are only appropriate for server side applications, since client side the secret needs to be embedded in software - and [thus only secret for so long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132392/636982) (could be reverse engineered).